# Data not returning Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am having issue with retuning php data in the form of array I have create an ajax query to show data on 2 div 1 is drop down and second is the div where all data wil be shown but the problem is that whEN i TRY to do so teh data all the data shows up in drop down and nothing effects second div can anyone help me out please

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#city").on('change', function() {
    var city = $('#city option:selected').text();

    $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
        $('#wait').css('opacity', '1');
    });

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
        $('#wait').css('opacity', '0');
    });

    $.ajax({
        type     :  "POST",
        data     :  {city: city, command: 'city'},
        dataType :  'JSON',
        url      :  "includes/get_data.php",
        success  :  function(data) {
            $("#location").html(data.city);
            $("#leads").html(data.lead);
        }
    });
});
});
```

Here is the get_data.php

```
if(isset($_POST["command"]) && $_POST['command'] == 'city') {
    $sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT DISTINCT location FROM doctors WHERE city = '".$_POST['city']."'");
    echo "<option> --- Select Location --- </option>";
    while($data1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        $data['city'] = "<option";
            if(isset($_POST['location']) == $data1['location']) {
                $data['city'] .= " selected";
            }
        $data['city'] .= ">".$data1['location']."</option>";
    }

    $sql2 = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM doctors WHERE city = '".$_POST['city']."'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql2) >= 1) {
        while($data2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql2)) {

        $data['lead']  = '<div class="postings doctor">';
        $data['lead'] .= '<div class="col-md-9"><div class="inner">';
        $data['lead'] .= '<h2>'.$data2['name'].'</h2>';
        $data['lead'] .= '<span>'.$data2['field'].'</span>';
        $data['lead'] .= '<p><'.$data2['qualification'].'</p>';
        $data['lead'] .= '<ul><li><span>Address</span>'.$data2['address'].'</li>';
        $data['lead'] .= '<li><span>Fee Range</span>'.$data2['fee_range'].'</li></ul></div></div>';
        $data['lead'] .= '<div class="col-md-3"><a href="details.php?id='.$data2['id'].'">View Details</a></div><div class="clearfix"></div></div>';
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: `data = JSON.parse(data);` or set the right header() in php

Comment: data = JSON.parse(data); I have to write this in my main.js where the js code i have written ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `echo "<option> --- Select Location --- </option>";` to get valid json :)

Comment: try to use the browser console `F12` and check for the response there, may you have see this earliery

Comment: I was trying console.log but was not getting anything i tried hitting by ctrl + f5 but nohing got

Comment: Browser? and write in the javascript `console.log(data):`, then check the right area in the develop tool (F12), you can also click in the network tab on the request too check the data, and read about the console how to access variables there